# Prisma Client Python with partent-child update

Tags: python, prisma

I'm using prisma and prostgresql and I have two related tables

```
model Search {
    id              String  @id @db.Uuid    @default(uuid())
    project         Project @relation(fields: [project_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
    project_id      String  @db.Uuid
    reference       Int?
    search_runs     SearchRun[]
    @@unique([project_id, reference])
}

model SearchRun {
    id              String  @id @db.Uuid    @default(uuid())
    search_id       String  @db.Uuid
    search          Search  @relation(fields: [search_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
    status          SearchStatus  
}
```

I want to do an update of the status of the status of all the searchRuns of a given project..

So I tried(with many variants):

```
db.search.update_many(
            data={
                "reference": None,
                "search_runs": {"update_many": {"data": {"status": SearchStatus.DELETED}}},
            },
            where={"project_id": project_id},
        )
```

and gives an error of Could not find field at `updateManySearch.data.search_runs`